# Does SWI-Prolog have a way to read scientific notation?

Tags: prolog

Does SWI-Prolog have a way to read scientific notation? I couldn't find anything here or in the document. For example, is there a way to read 7.33E-05 besides hard-parsing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to read numbers like 7.33E-05 is by using "read_term" predicate family, e.g.:

```
read_term_from_atom('7.33E-05', N, [])
```

should parse and save 7.33E-05 into variable N.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example use of the scientific notation:

```
 ?- X = 7.33E-05, Y = 6.4E-03, Z = X+Y, Y > X.
 X = 7.33e-5,
 Y = 0.0064,
 Z = 7.33e-5+0.0064.
```

To actually do simple math use:

```
 ?- use_module(library(clpr)).
 ?- X = 7.33E-05, Y = 6.4E-03, {Z=X+Y}.
 X = 7.33e-5,
 Y = 0.0064,
 Z = 0.0064733
```